# "Harlow Solid Italic" from Google Fonts doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having trouble getting the Harlow Solid Italic font to work. I have used a number of other fonts that range from Times New Roman to some Google Fonts such as Cinzel so I know that that I'm coding things the right way. Is there something that I'm missing here?

```
h1{
    font-family: 'Harlow Solid Italic';
}
```

Another thing that I tried to do was download the Harlow Solid Italic TTF and then install it into DreamWeaver. Using the same method above, but using a custom name (HarlowSI), I wasn't able to get it to work either.

Comment: check this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp 
you should define the font-family first.

Comment: Thanks, Leman17! That w3schools reference worked.

Comment: @leman17: would you add an answer, please?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not a problem statement, it's an opinion based on a preconception. Can you **proove** that it doesn't work with a jsbin.com example or the like?

Answer (score 5):

You have to define the font-family first. [For example](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
    font-family: "Harlow Solid"

Comment: That could work if "Harlow Solid" was a commonly available font that is already available in most browsers, like "Arial" or "Veranda," but this code would most likely just display the browser's default sans-serif font as there is no link to this font provided.